# How to modify multiple items in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to modify 2 things in my list.
`id` has to become `V1` and `field1` has to become `A`. After that I want to make a data-frame of just the dictionaries inside `the_list`. This is my expected outcome:

```
    V1    -     A
0   1     -     1
1   2     -     2
2   3     -     3
3   4     -     4
```

**This is my_list**

```
the_list = [['www.url1.com)', 1429, [{'id': 1, 'field1': None}, 
{'id': 2, 'field1': None}], 'www.url2.com'],  ['www.url1.com)', 1429, 
[{'id': 3, 'field1': None}, {'id': 4, 'field1': None}]]]
```

**This is my current code:**

```
for n, i in enumerate(the_list):
    if i == 'id':
        the_list[n] = 'V1'
    if i == 'field1':
        the_list[n] = 'A'
    
#print(the_list)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(the_list[2])

#print(df)
```

I did not receive any errors, my output was the same as the current state of `the_list`.

Comment: What was the output?

Comment: @pykam the same as  `the_list` in its current state.

Comment: Is the list structured the way you planned it ?? Seems a little strange at first sight.

Comment: As I understood from your explanation, you want to change the key of inner dictionaries. However, it is not possible to change it unless you define new keys with their values and remover the older ones.

Comment: Its not how I liked it to be but have to work with it like this...

Comment: @Pooria_T if thats the case then thats what I want. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to access the elements which represent the dictionaries in your `the_list`. For example: add the new key-value pairs `the_list[0][2][0]['v'] = 1` and remove the old one `the_list[0][2][0].pop('id')`. Build for loop to do it.

Comment: @Pooria_T can you show it as an answer in full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Better  to Change it Recursively to avoid the Errors Or you can use pandas rename method

```
the_list = [['www.url1.com)', 1429, [{'id': 1, 'field1': None}, 
{'id': 2, 'field1': None}], 'www.url2.com'],  ['www.url1.com)', 1429, 
[{'id': 3, 'field1': None}, {'id': 4, 'field1': None}]]]

def recursiveChange(the_list_tmp):
    for n, i in enumerate(the_list_tmp):
        if isinstance(i, list):
            the_list_tmp[n] = recursiveChange(i)
            continue
        if isinstance(i, dict):
            if 'id' in i:
                the_list_tmp[n]['V1'] = i['id']
                del the_list_tmp[n]['id']
                
            if 'field1' in i :
                the_list_tmp[n]['A'] = i['field1']
                del the_list_tmp[n]['field1'] 
        else:
            the_list_tmp[n] = i
    return the_list_tmp
    
the_list = recursiveChange(the_list)
print(the_list)

**OR**


the_list = [['www.url1.com)', 1429, [{'id': 1, 'field1': None}, 
{'id': 2, 'field1': None}], 'www.url2.com'],  ['www.url1.com)', 1429, 
[{'id': 3, 'field1': None}, {'id': 4, 'field1': None}]]]

df =  pd.DataFrame(the_list[0][2]).rename(columns={'id': 'V1', 'field1': 'A'})
print(df)
```

Comment: juneja looks quiet complex but seems to work. But what about the dataframe?

Comment: Try this: pd.DataFrame(the_list[0][2]).rename(columns={'id': 'V1', 'field1': 'A'})

Comment: what are the index 0 and 2 doing in your second code?

Comment: you list index 2 is inside a list , so first list index is 0 , second the actual data frame is index 2 , You entered the input like that

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list comprehension and pass it to the df constructor

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    list(each_dict.values())
    for complex in the_list
    for each_dict in complex[2]
    ], columns=['V1', 'A'])
    
print(df)

   V1     A
0   1  None
1   2  None
2   3  None
3   4  None
```

Notice how all the `field1` values are `None`, so they get read into the df as such

Comment: Now I tested before posting, remember to delete comments that are no longer relevant